# Where should I put the selectors for UIButtons in a reusable UIView?

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a single UIView I'm going to be adding to a few different views (like a navigation bar). Where should I put the selectors that I'm using for each button to keep the MVC structure?

My first guess would be to create a `NavButtonsViewController` but that seems funky since I'd have to instantiate the view controller somewhere in the UIView to add the target and selectors to the buttons. Or is that how it's supposed to work?

Answer (score 1):

I would probably model this on something like `UITableView` and have the view itself deal with the immediate gesture but provide a protocol so that a delegate could decide what should really be done.

The view's selectors would probably do nothing but forward to the delegate.

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly common to use a delegate for this kind of a problem. The view with the buttons would provide a delegate protocol that anyone can use to define behaviors that occur on an event.

The UINavigationBar and UINavigationBarDelegate are a good place to look for the delegation pattern similar to what you described.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationBar_Class/index.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationBarDelegate_Protocol/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I can think in two solutions if the view is reusable

**1-** Add the selectors in the `UIView` subclass and define a `protocol` where the delegate should take care of the actions in the View.

Header file

```
@protocol SubviewActionDelegate
@optional
- (void)button1Selected;
@end

@interface Subview: UIView
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<SubviewActionDelegate> delegate
@end
```

Implementation file

```
 [self.button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
...
- (IBAction)buttonSelected:(UIButton *)sender {
 if(self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(button1Selected)) {
    [self.delegate button1Selected];
     }
 }
```

The class that adds this reusable view as subview should implement this delegate and define itself as delegate.

**2-** Add the selectors in the same `UIView` or `UIViewcontroller` that add your view as subview.

```
Subview *view = [Subview alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
view.button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
...
- (void)buttonSelected:(id)sender{
   NSLog(@"Button selected");
}
```

Now if you have more than one of this reusable views in the same `UIViewController` or `UIView` container (like a `UITableViewCell`), you can identify which view is the one you are looking for by setting the view or button `tag` value.

```
[subview.button1 setTag:someValue]; 
...
- (void)buttonSelected:(UIButton *)sender{
   if(sender.tag == someValue) {
     //do something
   } else {
     //do something else
   }
```

Hope it helps